# How to catch exceptions for observables subscribed in Angular template?

Tags: angular, exception, angular2-observables

In an Angular (4.3.6) application I suscbribe observables in the temnplate with async pipe.

In some cases, when I get a 404 from an HTTP GET, the exception is bubbled up by Angular and the application become unresponsive.
I have seen I could use the `.catch()` method in my service, but non having directly a .subscribe() method in my component, how can I handle the exception?

**documentService**:

```
public getDocument() {
   return this.getDocument(serverUrl).catch((err) => this.handleError(err));
}

private handleError(error: Response) {
    return Observable.throw(error);
}
```

**component**:

```
public ngOnInit() {

   const document$ = this.reference$
        .filter((i) => !!i)
        .combineLatest(this.documentService.getBranch(),
        (r: any, branch: string) => {
            return this.documentService.getDocument(r.Id, r.targetId, this.GetHeadBranch(branch));
        }).switch();
   }
```

**template**:

```
<div *ngIf="document$|async; let document;">
  ....
</div>
```

Is there a best practice to catch exception with observables used like in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see [from the async source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.0.1/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L23), there is no way to instruct the pipe what to do when an error occurs. The pipe just throws the error. So it seems you have two choices:

You could create a pipe of your own that takes an additional parameter. Perhaps a callback function to execute when an error occurs. The callback could be passed the source observable along with the error thrown so you can display an appropriate error message and even resubscribe if you want.

You could use `catch`and handle the error in your service in a way that will format what gets returned so it's suitable for the view.

```
private handleError(error: Response) {
    // return Observable.throw(error); //will crash the app when fed to async pipe
    return Observable.of(this.errorDocument); //something the async pipe can display
}
```

[See my example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qstge4?file=app%2Fapp.service.ts)

Comment: Pity that there is not a better approach for dealing with exceptions yet. The custom pipe will require some extra steps (subscribe the observable, handle the value, redirect in case of exception), but if it can be made generic then it will be a win in the long run.